# Core Data relationship not saving even though it is set

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, save

I have a mandatory `genericCall` relationship for a `PlaylistCall` entity that is being set prior to the `PlaylistCall` being saved.  The logs show that the `genericCall` is not nil and yet I get a validation error when trying to save the managed object context stating that the relationship is not set.

What could cause a relationship that is already set to then become nil during the save?

What I have verified or attempted:

- I use a shared singleton as my managed object context for the entire app so I am definitely working within the same managed object context
- An inverse relationship exists between `GenericCall` and `PlaylistCall`
- On a whim, I tried deleting the relationship and then recreating it, but that did nothing so it seems like a bug in my code instead of a random bug in Xcode
- I tried using `setValue:forKey` instead of the dynamic property accessors (the dot notation) with no change

Here are the logs:

```
2013-03-25 11:48:35.400 Project[30599:c07] Supposed to add <PlaylistCall: 0xa1be450> (entity: PlaylistCall; id: 0xa17dea0 <x-coredata:///PlaylistCall/tBB209BC5-EF9A-4DAE-9A55-0001B97499392> ; data: {
    delaySetting = 0;
    genericCall = "0xd4ad520 <x-coredata://7EB1AFB2-7B49-431E-9700-275307B4D1C1/GenericCall/p367>";
    orderInTable = 4;
    playlist = nil;
    repeatSetting = 0;
    repeatType = 0;
    volumeSetting = 100;
}) with generic call <GenericCall: 0xd4c3fd0> (entity: GenericCall; id: 0xd4ad520 <x-coredata://7EB1AFB2-7B49-431E-9700-275307B4D1C1/GenericCall/p367> ; data: {
    animalCategory = "0xc0aaa80 <x-coredata://7EB1AFB2-7B49-431E-9700-275307B4D1C1/AnimalCategory/p19>";
    callDescription = "Call Name";
    numberOfTimesOnPlaylist = 0;
    numberOfTimesPlayed = 0;
    playlistCall = "0xa17dea0 <x-coredata:///PlaylistCall/tBB209BC5-EF9A-4DAE-9A55-0001B97499392>";
    soundFile = "sound_file_name";
    timeLength = "0.21";
})
2013-03-25 11:48:35.402 Project[30599:c07] Error saving.  Reason(s): 
    PlaylistCall: The attribute 'genericCall' cannot be empty.
```

Here is how I am setting and saving the values:

```
GenericCall *genericCall = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
PlaylistCall *playlistCall = (PlaylistCall *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PlaylistCall" inManagedObjectContext:commonContext.managedObjectContext];
[self.playlist addPlaylistCall:playlistCall withGenericCall:genericCall orderInTable:[self.playlist.playlistCalls count]];
// Note: all other attributes are setup via model defaults
[commonContext save];
```

My NSManagedObject subclass for `Playlist` where I set the relationship:

```
- (void)addPlaylistCall:(PlaylistCall *)playlistCall withGenericCall:(GenericCall *)genericCall orderInTable:(int)orderInTable
{
    NSMutableOrderedSet *tempSet = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithOrderedSet:self.playlistCalls];
    playlistCall.genericCall = genericCall;
    playlistCall.orderInTable = [NSNumber numberWithInt:orderInTable];
    NSLog(@"Supposed to add %@ with generic call %@", playlistCall, playlistCall.genericCall);
    [tempSet addObject:playlistCall];
    self.playlistCalls = tempSet;
}
```

My common managed object context singleton (`CommonContext`) just looks like this (and yes I've verified that the `self.managedObjectContext` is not nil and doesn't change):

```
// Saves the managed object context
- (BOOL)save
{
    NSError *anError;
    if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![self.managedObjectContext save:&anError]){
        [self handleSaveError:anError];
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Any ideas for what I may be doing wrong?  It seems straightforward and I use this same approach everywhere else in my app for setting relationships, so there has to be something that I am missing.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to be certain but here's a scenario that fits the symptoms:

1. You look up an existing `GenericCall` instance before creating a new `PlaylistCall`. But this `GenericCall` *already has* a non-`nil` value for `playlistCall`.
2. You make the assignment `playlistCall.genericCall = genericCall` using the new `PlaylistCall`.
3. The already-existing `PlaylistCall` instance has its `genericCall` relationship set to `nil`-- because this is a one-to-one relationship and that's the default behavior in this case.
4. Saving fails-- not because of the new `PlaylistCall` you created, which is fine, but because of the previous `PlaylistCall` that has been left with a dangling `genericCall` relationship.

If this is what's happening, you'll need to check for an existing `playlistCall` and do something reasonable with it before saving changes-- most likely either reassigning its `genericCall` to point to something else, or possibly just deleting the instance.

Comment: Your comment about the `genericCall` already having a non-nil value for `playlistCall` is what did it.  For whatever reason, I had a `playlistCall` relationship setup on the `GenericCall` entity even though it should have been a to-many relationship (`playlistCalls`) so I kept re-assigning the relationship every time.  Thanks for the wisdom!  By the way, I'd be dead in the water without your Core Data book.  It has consistently saved me time and time again so thanks for writing it!

Comment: I just experienced this exact same problem and I had done exactly the same thing (set a to-one relationship rather than a to-many) relationship. Thank god for StackOverflow and the wonderful people who post answers!